# Returning Query Result

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm writing this application in PHP where the user has a "Student's Name" and each user has a unique student name. So, before I go any further with my problem, here is the code
*Note I've already prevented the SQL injections

```
    function hello($username123) {
       // Connect to Database //
$host3     = "db"; 
$username3 = "db"; 
$password3 = "db"; 
$db3       = "db";
$con3 = mysqli_connect($host3,$username3,$password3,$db3) or die("Can not connect to Server.");
$query3 = mysqli_query($con3,"SELECT student1 FROM users WHERE username = '$username123'");
$student1name = "$query3";
return $student1name;
```

So, the person enters the username which the registered before hand and each user has a student name.I start a query which selects student1 and student1 is equal to student1name. Student 1 name is then defnied as query3. When I test it all out, all I get is (null).. Does anyone know the problem? Thank you!

Comment: `mysqli_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());` You are mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` queries, another thing ... you asked this question and we gave you a perfectly logical answer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I've since fixed this problem and I still get a return of `(null)`

Comment: @user1666767: how do you know you're returning `null`? What's the `$student1name` variable for?

Comment: I know I'm returning null because I'm using this code to use in AMFPHP (An open source library for easily connecting Flash and PHP) Preferably I'd like to just return $student1name.

Comment: @user1666767: "I know I'm returning null because I'm using this code to use in AMFPHP" --- nope, you don't know that. `$query3` is a string, so you're returning it, not `NULL`

Comment: Your code is simply, out of logic. It just won't work. Read why, in my answer.

Comment: @zerkms Yes, but when I call the function I simply get `(null)`

Comment: @user1666767: it's not possible

Comment: Please reorganize your logic before writing the codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you want is something like this:

```
function hello($username123) {
    // Connect to Database //
    $host3     = "db"; 
    $username3 = "db"; 
    $password3 = "db"; 
    $db3       = "db";
    $con3 = mysqli_connect($host3,$username3,$password3,$db3) or die("Can not connect to Server.");
    $query3 = mysqli_query($con3,"SELECT student1 FROM users WHERE username = '$username123'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query3))
    {
        $student1name = $row['student1'];
    }
    return $student1name;
```

This will put the contents of *the last returned row* of your query, column "student1", into the variable $student1name, and return it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not fetching data from result. Try this:

```
function hello($username123) {
    // Connect to Database //
    $host3     = "db"; 
    $username3 = "db"; 
    $password3 = "db"; 
    $db3       = "db";

    $con3 = mysqli_connect($host3,$username3,$password3,$db3)
    if (!$con3)
        throw new Exception("Connection error");

    $result = mysqli_query($con3,"SELECT student1 FROM users WHERE username = '$username123'");
    if ($result)
        return $result->fetch_object();
    else
        throw new Exception("Query error: " . mysqli_error($con3));
}
```